# Exporting 3d Models and their color information using Assimp

Tags: opengl, 3d, export, assimp

we're working on a custom 3d engine (OpenGL) in which people can create, import and export custom 3d models, and we are using Assimp for our importing/exporting. At this point, importing works great, but when it comes to exporting, we are unable to save out any materials other than the default. While Assimp's website and others have loads of information on importing, there is little to no documentation on exporting. We managed to work out majority of the export process, but there doesn't seem to be any way of setting Assimp's aiMaterials' color values.

Assimp's documentation explains how to GET the color information from existing materials, ie..

> *aiColor3D color (0.f,0.f,0.f);
>
> mat->Get(AI_MATKEY_COLOR_DIFFUSE,color);*
>
> http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/materials.html

but doesn't include anything on SETTING color information based on the model's material. (FYI, all of our models are flat colors; no textures). If anyone has any experience in exporting materials/colors, any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is what we have now..

```
//Create an Assimp node element to be a container object to hold all graphic information

scene.mRootNode = new aiNode();

scene.mMaterials = new aiMaterial*[ 1 ];
scene.mMaterials[ 0 ] = nullptr;
scene.mNumMaterials = 1;

mAllChildren.clear();
//Get ALL children on the scene (including down the hierarchy)
FindAllChildren(CScriptingUtils::GetDoc()->GetScene());
std::vector<std::weak_ptr<CNode>> children = mAllChildren;
int size = (int)children.size();
scene.mMaterials[ 0 ] = new aiMaterial();

scene.mRootNode->mMeshes = new unsigned int[ size ];
scene.mRootNode->mNumMeshes = size;
scene.mMeshes = new aiMesh*[ size ];
scene.mNumMeshes = size;

//Iterate through all children, retrieve their graphical information and push it into the Assimp structure
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    std::shared_ptr<CNode> childNode = children[i].lock();
    scene.mRootNode->mMeshes[ i ] = i;
    scene.mMeshes[ i ] = nullptr;
    scene.mMeshes[ i ] = new aiMesh();
    scene.mMeshes[ i ]->mMaterialIndex = 0;

    aiMaterial* mat = scene.mMaterials[0];
```

And we need to do something like..

```
    mat.color = childNode.color;
```

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
mat->AddProperty<aiColor3D>(color, 1, AI_MATKEY_COLOR_DIFFUSE);
```

It helps me. Also, I trying to export textures

```
newMat->AddProperty(matName, AI_MATKEY_NAME);
newMat->AddProperty(texturePath, AI_MATKEY_TEXTURE_DIFFUSE(0));
```

where 'matName' and 'texturePath' types are 'aiString'. What additiional parameters (besides path of texture) needed for correct displaying texture (because now textures not displayed, only color)?

Comment: I understood. I haven't texture coords. So export textures also works.For me, at least)